# Is using event.stopPropagation() in each child element good practice?

Tags: javascript

I recently stumbled upon Javascript's event.stopPropagation() method, when I say stumbled I mean exactly that, and was wondering if it's good practice to use at all times.  For instance, if I have a parent element that has a click handler

```
<div id="parent"></div>
var parentElm = document.getElementById("parent");
parentElm.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
    console.log("Hello parent");
})
```

and a child element that also has a click handler

```
<div id="parent"><div id="child"></div></div>
var parentElm = document.getElementById("parent");
var childElm = parentElm.getElementById("child");
parentElm.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
    console.log("Hello parent");
})
childElm.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
    console.log("Hello child");
})
```

From what I understand and what I've seen, both console log messages will be displayed since you are in-fact clicking on both elements.  So is it good practice to always call event.stopPropagation() at the beginning of the child element?  Although it's not good to nest click handlers, would the following not accomplish the same feat?

```
<div id="parent"><div id="child"></div></div>
var parentElm = document.getElementById("parent");
var childElm = parentElm.getElementById("child");
parentElm.addEventListener("click", function(parentEvent){
    console.log("Hello parent");
    childElm.addEventListener("click", function(childEvent){
        parentEvent.preventDefault();
        console.log("Hello child");
    })
})
```

Comment: Third code example would ad an `EventListener` to `childElm` *every time* you click its parent and `console.log("Hello child");` would be executed more than once for every click.

Comment: If you don't want the parent function to execute when clicking the child, then yes, use `stopPropagation();` where it's needed.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of multiple event objects binded to eventListeners that way. I've always used the de facto `e` or `event`

Comment: Some people prefer checking `event.defaultPrevented` to know if the event has already been handled by a descendant which does `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: `stopPropagation` can interfere with event delegation to dynamically-added elements.

Comment: @Oriol so using `parentEvent.preventDefault();` and `childEvent.preventDefault();` we can tell them apart? Good to know, thanks.

Comment: [The Dangers of Stopping Event Propagation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)